# chrome renders js different depending on the extension of the file to render [testcase included]

Tags: xhtml, jsf, google-chrome, content-type, facelets

I was trying to implement an image panner I found [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagepanner.htm)
Chrome renders the same document differently depending on the extension of the file requested. I have created a test case, where it works when the file it's **not** named as test.**xhtml**

You can download the test case from [here](http://www.eyeprevent.nl/testcase.tar.gz)

Does anybody know why or how to solve it? I want my files to be .xhtml
In IE and FF it works fine.

Code:
test.html / test.xhtml (change the name to see that works with one but not with the other).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<style type="text/css">
/*Default CSS for pan containers*/
.pancontainer {
    position: relative; /*keep this intact*/
    overflow: hidden; /*keep this intact*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagepanner.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pancontainer" data-orient="center" data-canzoom="yes" style="width: 350px; height: 200px; float: left; position: relative; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; cursor: move; "><img src="./test_files/image.jpg" style="position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 525px; left: -175px; top: -163px; display: block;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:
Apparently, thanks to the comments is tomcat which is sending application/xhtml+xml as Content-Type.

```
HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS  
--> HTTP/1.1 200 OK            
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1  
X-Powered-By: JSF/1.2      
Pragma: no-cache           
Cache-Control: no-cache    
Cache-Control: no-store    
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 07:39:30 GMT
```

I've added a mime-type to the `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>xhtml</extension>
<mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

But still does not work. I belive that `FacesServlet` is reading the file extension and sending the content-type, overriding the configuration in `web.xml`

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

I've tried to modify the web.xml configuration to change .xhtml to .html, but Faces Servlet serves the files as application/xhtml+xml I guess I could add a filter to the webapp modifying the Content-Type to text/html but that's a bit hacky.

Why JSF with Facelets does not serve the files as html? Or how to do so?

**Update** Found how to serve text/html from JSF. You need to add

```
<f:view contentType="text/html"/>
```

after `<html>` and before `<head>`

Now it works as expected in chrome.

Comment: Using a XHTML doctype with a text/html has no positive effects, it will only force the browser into quirks mode.
To serve XHTML, and have it parsed as XML, you **must** serve it as 'application/xhtml+xml'.  Why not use the HTML5 doctype? It is more permissive and both back- and forward compatible..

Comment: Btw, are you opening this locally or via a web server? If locally, then Chrome probably tries to guess the content-type based on the extension.

Comment: @Sean Both, locally and via webserver (Tomcat) it has the same problem.

Comment: @pakore: Have you checked the mime type tomcat is serving it with? Are you certain that it actually knows the correct mime type to send .xhtml files with?

Comment: @Sean_Kinsey you were right, tomcat is sending application/xhtml+xm instead of text/html. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly, but what I do know is that when you use .xhtml extension on a local file in Chrome, then the file is parsed using the XML parser, and if you use a .html extension on a local file, then it's parsed using the HTML parser.

This is easy to prove. Add `<span>` at the bottom of each file, to make it non-XML-well-formed and try to open it. You'll get a big warning message saying that it could only process up to the error with the .xhtml file, but it will be silently ignored in the .html file.

(Incidentally, the DOCTYPE has no effect on this whatsoever.)

Quite why it doesn't work when XML parsed is less clear, but it may be down to the fact that jQuery uses the innerHTML property in some cases, which shouldn't work with XML parsed DOMs.

Comment: You are right, I did the "span" thing and it does not render properly. See my update. Thanks.

Comment: Finally I found the answer thanks to your tip. I managed to configure properly the content-type of the page. Although Lazarus was right as well, you have less karma so I accepted your question to spread the karma wealth :P.

Answer (score 2):

The DOCTYPE denotes what kind of standard is used, a .html file with a DOCTYPE of XHTML is processed as XHTML. Not sure why Chrome is behaving differently with the extension .xhtml, it's probably forcing some kind of default DOCTYPE and ignoring the contained one. XHTML has been abandoned now in favour of HTML 5, not sure your current route is one you want to follow to the letter albeit that XHTML will render in an HTML 5 browser.

Comment: This is a testcase for something i'm doing with jsf. AFAIK jsf does not render html5  yet. Besides html5 is not finished yet, right? Thanks for the answer though, I don't know why chrome is ignoring the content-type tag.

Comment: As @Sean_Kinsey mentions, the HTML5 doctype is both forward and backward compatible (i.e. you won't break anything by specifying it). What is it specifically about XHTML that you want to use?

Comment: Lazarus, I finally fixed it. Thanks to your tips. If I could mark your question as valid as well I would do it!

Comment: Your claim that “XHTML has been abandoned now in favour of HTML 5” is incorrect. Far from being abandoned, it is a standard part of HTML 5. See W3C standard §§ [HTML vs XML Syntax](http://w3c.github.io/html/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) and [The XML syntax](http://w3c.github.io/html/xhtml.html#xhtml).

Comment: @MichaelAllan You are correct in that it's not officially abandoned by the W3C but in my experience, the focus is very much on the HTML syntax not the XHTML variant.